# If I'm using Google Tag Manager, can I still make "manual" calls to analytics.js?

Tags: google-tag-manager

If I'm using GTM and I'm calling a Google Analytics Pageview on MyPage, can I also make a call (after the call to invoke the GTM code) directly to analytics.js, such as:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', 'page path');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, seems odd that you would, but you just need to know the name of the tracker object created by GTM (or you can also tell GTM to use a named tracker). Once you know the tracker name, you can then use the ga function call like this;

```
ga('gtm1234578.send', 'pageview')
```

where the tracker name is, for example, gtm12345678.